# onActivityResult is never called by Google SignIn after verifying the new user

Tags: android

```
private void getSignIn() {

    Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_GET_AUTH_CODE);
}
```

In the above code, `onActivityResult` is never called by Google SignIn after verifying the new user.
Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Comment: are you calling this method from fragment ?

Comment: if you are calling this in fragment then make sure to implement the onActivityResult in parent activity

Comment: @HiteshSarsava No, I am calling from Activity only

Comment: @vikaskumar agreed.i have done the same.

Comment: you need to explain a bit or show the code how you are using the above snippet

Comment: @satheesh you are making me confuse. you told vikashkumar that you are calling this method from fragment.

Comment: @HiteshSarsavaI meant that I have verified it is not calling from the fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Things to take care.

1. Check whether you are use this in fragment or activity. If you are using this in fragment check `onActivityResult` of your container or host Activity.
2. If you are calling this in Activity, Check you does your Activity extends any other activity, if yes then check `onActivity` result of your parent activity.

Comment: I have checked both the cases. Still, it is not working.

Comment: can you please post your code? That will be more easy to resolve problem.